# generalizations of semi-continuity theorems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I would like to know some references (if any) about the generalization of the semicontinuity theorem and "Cohomology and base change" theorem (theorems 12.8 and 12.11 in the book "Algebraic geometry" of Hartshorne). Generalizations to non projective (maybe proper) morphisms. And also generalizations of "Grauert theorem" (corollary 12.9) to a non integral base $Y$.

Comment: The semicontinuity and base change theorems hold verbatim for proper morphisms; a nice reference is Mumford's *Abelian varieties*, §II.5. On the other hand the Grauert theorem certainly doesn't hold without assuming $Y$ reduced — there are easy counter-examples.

Comment: @abx thank you for this reference.